# Image or font awesome as option in select - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, html-select

I would like to have an input select with a choice of image as an option (would define a custom icon). I can put an image or an icon with Font awesome.
I tried putting

```
<select>
 <option><i class='fas fa-shopping-bag'/></option>
<select>
```

or replace  with an image but nothing work.
Font Awesome font is well imported, I tried with unicode it does not work either
Do you know how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using reactjs you need to use className instead of class https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html